# Python 3 Yolo darknet load_image The <class TypeError'>

Tags: python-3.x, yolo, darknet

Hi stackoverflow community, i facing the problem when i try to load image into detect function from string format and i get 'TypeError'

Here is the code:

```
Load_image = '/data/image_01.jpg'
res =(net,meta,Load_image)
```

please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get some answer after some try.
if want to locate a string directory for detect class need to add .encode("utf-8")
because when python convert back to C++ it needed this way

```
Load_image = '/data/image_01.jpg'.encode("utf-8")
res =(net,meta,Load_image)

OR

Load_image = '/data/image_01.jpg'.encode("utf-8")
dataimage = Load_image.encode("utf-8")
res=(net,meta,dataimage)
```

Hope this help others who needed.